# Keras extremely high loss, not decreasing with each epoch

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, theano, keras

I'm using Keras to build and train a recurrent neural network.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Masking
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM

#build and train model
in_dimension = 3
hidden_neurons = 300
out_dimension = 2

model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking([0,0,0], input_shape=(max_sequence_length, in_dimension)))
model.add(LSTM(hidden_neurons, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(max_sequence_length, in_dimension)))
model.add(LSTM(hidden_neurons, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(out_dimension))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop")
model.fit(padded_training_seqs, training_final_steps, nb_epoch=5, batch_size=1)
```

`padded_training_seqs` is an an array of sequences of [latitude, longitude, temperature], all padded to the same length with values of [0,0,0]. When I train this network, the first epoch gives me a loss of about 63, and *increases* after more epochs.
This is causing a `model.predict` call later in the code to give values that are completely off of the training values. For example, most of the training values in each sequence is around `[40, 40, 20]`, but the RNN outputs values consistently around `[0.4, 0.5]`, which causes me to think something is wrong with the masking layer.

The training X (`padded_training_seqs`) data looks something like this (only much larger):

```
[
[[43.103, 27.092, 19.078], [43.496, 26.746, 19.198], [43.487, 27.363, 19.092], [44.107, 27.779, 18.487], [44.529, 27.888, 17.768]], 
[[44.538, 27.901, 17.756], [44.663, 28.073, 17.524], [44.623, 27.83, 17.401], [44.68, 28.034, 17.601], [0,0,0]],
[[47.236, 31.43, 13.905], [47.378, 31.148, 13.562], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]
]
```

and the training Y (`training_final_steps`) data looks like this:

```
[
[44.652, 39.649], [37.362, 54.106], [37.115, 57.66501]
]
```

Comment: An increasing loss function when training always makes me suspicious of running with a too high learning rate. Have you tried reducing that, you can adjust this by passing in an `keras.optimizers.RMSprop` instance to the `model.compile` call.

Comment: @SimonGibbons Thanks, but I've fixed this problem but now a model.predict call is always returning the same value, regardless of the x data fed into it. Do you know what could be causing this? The entire project is here https://github.com/jeshaitan/migration-lstm

Comment: Hi, how did you fix your problem? Are you really having high learning rate? From your program, I guess you are using the default learning rate, which is 0.01 right?

Comment: @ChangLiu  Yeah, I just added a dropout layer and rearranged the layers in the model as suggested to me by a Keras maintainer. My new problem is yet to be solved, however. I think it might be the network overfitting, because model.predict converges on one value.

Comment: @ChangLiu my new question is basically outlined here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204329/keras-predictive-ann-model-converging-on-a-single-value-overfitting

Answer (score 0):

I am somewhat certain that you're misusing the Masking layer from Keras. Check the documentation [here](http://keras.io/layers/core/#masking) for more details.

Try using a masking layer like:

`model.add(Masking(0, input_shape=(max_sequence_length, in_dimension)))`

because I believe it just needs the masking value in the timestep dimension, not the entire time-dimension and value (ie [0,0,0]).

Best of luck.